# How to trigger Finder's Move File Dialog programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, finder

I'm working on a small Cocoa utility that lets the user drag files onto its window and then moves those to a different folder.

Instead of moving the dragged file myself (via `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] performFileOperation:NSWorkspaceMoveOperation...]`), I would like to trigger Finder's "Move File Dialog". This will give the user visual feedback (progress bar) and take care of error handling (e.g. file at target exists).

I've thought about using an Apple Script, but maybe there's an easier way to bring up that dialog?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should check the NSFileManager.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: NSFileManager provides only _low level_ file system functions. I'm looking for a high level way to handle moving files (e.g. showing a progress dialog, asking for confirmation to replace a file,...). Thanks anyway.